# BigQuery and Standard SQL: how to find number of occurence by day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Big Query database in the following format:

```
p_time          q_id
2019-12-12   12345
...                    ...
```

I want to create a table that lists how many times the p_id appears on any given date. The `q_id` corresponds to a name and I have a corresponding database and I want to see the name.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You mention `p_id`, but it is not in the data you provide.  Then the text mentions a "name", but that reference seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to results aggregated by date and id, you will need a `GROUP BY` on the date and id.

Because you want to count the number of rows, you will need a `COUNT` in the select list.

So you probably want a query like:

```
SELECT
  p_time,
  q_id,
  COUNT(*) total
FROM
  table_name
GROUP BY
  p_time, q_id;
```